# Python files missing

Tags: python, latex, purge

I committed a big mistake. I issued the following command on my terminal

```
sudo apt-get purge python
```

I didn't read what it removed :(

I use LaTeX typesetting system and some of it's packages are not working now. I've asked my question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/504659/174620).

If I've lost the python files, is it needed to reinstall the full OS or something else might help me out of this?

---

Log -

```
Start-Date: 2019-08-17  13:55:17
Commandline: apt-get purge python
Requested-By: ubuntu (1000)
Purge: python-webencodings:amd64 (0.5-2), python-six:amd64 (1.11.0-2), python-matplotlib:amd64 (2.1.1-2ubuntu3), vprerex:amd64 (1:6.5.1-1), python-cycler:amd64 (0.10.0-1), feynmf:amd64 (1.08-10), fragmaster:amd64 (1.7-5), python-xdg:amd64 (0.25-4ubuntu1), python-gi:amd64 (3.26.1-2ubuntu1), latex-cjk-all:amd64 (4.8.4+git20170127-2), python-tk:amd64 (2.7.16-2~18.04.york0), python-tz:amd64 (2018.3-2), python-dbus:amd64 (1.2.6-1), python-chardet:amd64 (3.0.4-1), texlive-pictures:amd64 (2017.20180305-1), python-pyparsing:amd64 (2.2.0+dfsg1-2), python-subprocess32:amd64 (3.2.7-3), python:amd64 (2.7.16-1~18.04.york0), python-lxml:amd64 (4.2.1-1ubuntu0.1), python-enum34:amd64 (1.1.6-2), texlive-xetex:amd64 (2017.20180305-1), qbittorrent:amd64 (4.0.3-1), lyx:amd64 (2.2.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), texlive-latex-extra:amd64 (2017.20180305-2), python-cryptography:amd64 (2.1.4-1ubuntu1.3), python-crypto:amd64 (2.6.1-8ubuntu2), texlive-music:amd64 (2017.20180305-2), python-keyrings.alt:amd64 (3.0-1), python-cffi-backend:amd64 (1.11.5-1), python-ipaddress:amd64 (1.0.17-1), python-olefile:amd64 (0.45.1-1), prerex:amd64 (6.5.4-1), texlive-lang-other:amd64 (2017.20180305-1), texlive-full:amd64 (2017.20180305-1), python-scour:amd64 (0.36-2), python-pkg-resources:amd64 (39.0.1-2), python-html5lib:amd64 (0.999999999-1), python-all:amd64 (2.7.16-1~18.04.york0), inkscape:amd64 (0.92.3-1), python-bs4:amd64 (4.6.0-1), texlive-pstricks:amd64 (2017.20180305-2), python-secretstorage:amd64 (2.3.1-2), python-dev:amd64 (2.7.16-1~18.04.york0), python-setuptools:amd64 (39.0.1-2), python-keyring:amd64 (10.6.0-1), lyx-common:amd64 (2.2.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.1), texlive-formats-extra:amd64 (2017.20180305-2), python-idna:amd64 (2.6-1), python-wheel:amd64 (0.30.0-0.2), texlive-science:amd64 (2017.20180305-2), asymptote:amd64 (2.41-4), python-dateutil:amd64 (2.6.1-1), latex-cjk-thai:amd64 (4.8.4+git20170127-2), python-numpy:amd64 (1:1.13.3-2ubuntu1), texlive-extra-utils:amd64 (2017.20180305-2), python-pil:amd64 (5.1.0-1), python-pip:amd64 (9.0.1-2.3~ubuntu1.18.04.1), python-asn1crypto:amd64 (0.24.0-1), python-backports.functools-lru-cache:amd64 (1.4-2), python-all-dev:amd64 (2.7.16-1~18.04.york0)
End-Date: 2019-08-17  13:59:03
```

Comment: You didn't tell us what release of Ubuntu you are using; the effect is less on later release of Ubuntu (as they rely more on python3), however you can read in /var/log/apt/ what else was removed (and should be re-installed). You may find some package tools no longer work, so you may need to re-install using `dpkg` instead of higher-level `apt` tools

Comment: @guiverc sorry I didn't mention it. I'm using ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I've added the log that I found in the answer. Is there any way to undo all of these these unistallations in one command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied your list and compared it with the programms I have installed (Ubuntu 19.04). Then I removed every package that was makred "automatically" at my system. They will be installed on your system, too but marked as "automatically" too.

```
sudo apt install asymptote feynmf fragmaster inkscape latex-cjk-all latex-cjk-thai lyx lyx-common prerex python-all python python-bs4 python-chardet python-crypto python-cycler python-dbus python-gi python-html5lib python-idna python-keyring python-lxml python-matplotlib python-pil python-pkg-resources python-pyparsing python-secretstorage python-six python-subprocess32 python-tz python-xdg qbittorrent texlive-extra-utils texlive-formats-extra texlive-full texlive-lang-other texlive-music texlive-pstricks texlive-science texlive-xetex vprerex
```

That are all the programms you have to install. The "automatically" marked programms will follow. If you want to verify if the rest is installed you may run

```
apt list python-all-dev python-asn1crypto python-backports.functools-lru-cache python-cffi-backend python-cryptography python-dateutil python-dev python-enum34 python-ipaddress python-keyrings.alt python-numpy python-olefile python-pip python-scour python-setuptools python-tk python-webencodings python-wheel texlive-latex-extra texlive-pictures
```

and check if the rest was installed. If not, install each of the missing as "manually".

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I tried what you mentioned here, everything is installed as of now, but still my TeX programme is not working perfectly, why do you think this is so?

Comment: Do you have `texlive-latex-recommended` istalled? You can check it by usinge `apt list texlive-latex-recommended`.

Comment: Yes, I have it installed.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --install-suggests --reinstall texlive` to reinstall texlive and all the suggested libarys again

Comment: Thanks, it worked!